# Fit 8 elements inside one div using only css

Tags: html, css

I just started my adventure with html/css/js and I have to say I really am enjoying it, but sometimes got stuck on some problems like this one.

This is the content of the task:

Create div that width is set on 80% and is always centered. Inside this div fit 8 more divs that has the following characteristics:

Height: 50px;

Width: 33%;

Margin-right: 5%;

The main goal of this task is to fit all 8 divs and make them go to the next line/row.

This is my attempt to solve this task. All of this need to be solved with using css.

```
**https://codepen.io/Zeykie/pen/KKNLXZg**
```

All help is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you want all 8 divs in one row ??

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You have to just remove the margin from every 3rd child of `.container`.

Please refer to this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/j0dvfcxg/

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  background: green;
}

.container>div:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes it`s looks good. Soory for the late answer, but my job as well as diffrent timezone didn`t allow me to respond quicker.